# AddThis Layers in Full Screen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, addthis

I'm making a **slideshow with full screen functionality** *(FancyBox 3)*, it's using the `RequestFullScreen` method on the container div, which means any other element in the body is not accessible in full screen mode. *(correct me if i'm wrong)*

I would like to include an **AddThis Expanding Share** button in the slideshow, but because it's created dynamically by the AddThis js, it appends the **Smart Layers** before the end of the body, not **at the end of the slideshow container div** therefore it's not included in the full screen slideshow.

I couldn't find any info on Smart Layers DOM placement in the AddThis API.

*What I've tried is seems like a bad idea, to manually `appendTo` the necessary divs to the slideshow container after the divs are created by AddThis, I managed to "cut and paste" the `'.at-expanding-share-button'` and it's working so far, but I can't "catch" the `'#at-expanded-menu-host'` (which is the layer created by AddThis for more sharing options, with the dark background), and I'm not even sure if this method will work properly...*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The explanation of your problem is very good, but how about posting some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I figured it out! :) I thought I share my experience/solution, if anyone has similar difficulties.*

**What won't work and why:**

- First I've tried to communicate with the AddThis API to tell it to put its layers to a premade container, which looks like impossible and **the** **AddThis team also told me that there is no solution for manual layer DOM placement**, it's always appending those to the end of the body *(at least for now, maybe they will implement this option into their API)*.
- Then I've tried to **manually append those layers to the Fancy-Box container**, which was a dead end because **when the slideshow closes, it removes its container from the markup**, so the AddThis layers disappeared and I couldn't reinit it *(maybe others have some solution for that, but I just couldn't figure it out)*.
- *By the way, the "More Sharing Options" layer is created when the share + button is clicked.*

**My solution:**

- Instead of appending the layers to the dynamic slideshow container, **I've created a static div at the end of the body, appended the layers to it when they are created, and set the Fancy-Box parent div to my container** *(note that Fancy-Box full screen functionality makes its own div into full screen, so I had to use my own full screen function for the container with the layers and the slideshow)*.

I've used [sindresorhus's screenfull](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) for easier/cross-browser full screen functions.

```
    var FullScreenContainer = $('#container');

    // Check if AddThis Layers are ready
    var checkLayers = setInterval(function() { appendLayers(); }, 1000);
        // Append the layers to FullScreenContainer
        function appendLayers() {
            var layers = $('.at-expanding-share-button, #_atssh');
            if(layers.length > 0){
                addthis.layers.refresh();
                layers.appendTo(FullScreenContainer);
                clearInterval(checkLayers);
                console.log('layers added');
            }
            else {
                console.log('not found')
            }
        }
    // Check for more layers when the share icon clicked
    $(document).on('click', ".at-expanding-share-button-toggle", function() {
            var checkMoreLayers = setInterval(function() { catchLayers(); }, 1000);
            function catchLayers() {
                var morelayers = $('#at-expanded-menu-host');
                if(morelayers.length > 0){
                    morelayers.appendTo(FullScreenContainer);
                    clearInterval(checkMoreLayers);
                    console.log('more layers added');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('did not found more')
                }
            }
    });

    // Don't forget to disable the full screen function in Fancy-Box, 
    // then call them when necessary (onInit, clickSlide, clickOutside 
    // and the close button)
    function enterFullscreen() {
        screenfull.request($('#container')[0]);
    }
    function exitFullscreen() {
        if (screenfull.isFullscreen) {
            screenfull.exit();
            $.fancybox.getInstance().close();
        }
        if (!screenfull.isFullscreen) {
            $.fancybox.getInstance().close();
        }
    }
```

And you are good to go. I hope this helps for anybody else! :)